# Does the expression "to go under the knife" carry a negative connotation?

Tags: expressions, idioms, word-usage, register

Is there a difference in connotation between these two phrases?

1. I asked my student whether her mother was scheduled to GO UNDER THE KNIFE this morning.
2. I asked my student whether her mother was scheduled to UNDERGO SURGERY this morning.

In other words, would it be polite to ask somebody the question "When's she going under the knife?" in the informal register? Or would it sound too brutal or insensitive? (The "knife" part makes me think of a butcher, to be honest.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has the negative connotation that one is about to undergo surgery!

Since no surgery is completely without risk, and most is followed by a period of pain or discomfort, any expression describing it inherently contains a negative.

For that reason, we might euphemistically talk of "going into theatre"; a form of synecdoche, where the act of going into the place where surgery is performed stands for the whole process of going in there and having surgery performed. (We also use the same euphemism of the surgeons, theatre nurses, anesthesiologist, etc. who perform the surgery).

"Go under the knife" is a mild dysphemism, that doesn't add a negative connotation so much as focus on that which is already there.

This sort of bluntness can have a sort of euphemistic effect though, in a manner not unakin to gallows humour. Some people find it more comfortable to address the negative than to talk around it.

This sort of bluntness would require a degree of familiarity to be appropriate, and from that the ability to judge whether the person hearing it would indeed be the sort to prefer it.

It's also favoured as a dysphemism in more impersonal, informal writing. In journalism we'll find it used more of elective procedures, than for emergency or clearly required procedures, because "chose to go under the knife" both efficiently covers that a risk, and often a subsequent period of pain and discomfort, was entailed in that choice, as well as being a more vivid expression than the alternatives.

Comment: Surgery is frightening and worrisome, but, to me, this is not what a negative connotation means. Synonyms of negative include pessimistic, defeatist, gloomy, cynical, fatalistic, dismissive, antipathetic, critical, etc. Tumor removal, eyesight restoration, organ transplants, etc. are all cause for celebration to me.

Comment: @J.R. - I'm more concerned perhaps with this statement: "any expression describing it is inherently negative." But I agree with you that it's hard for most of us to celebrate going in. :) I imagine that isn't the case for transplant recipients, however. They pray for the opportunity.

Comment: @Susan you are including in "cause for celebration" cases that I have lost family to. There is always a negative aspect to surgery, though I've rephrased to "always contains a negative". Even with the positive cases, while it's positive to *have had* a tumour removed, eyesight restored or an organ transplant, and positive to *be going to* have them, the point in time when you are having them is likely to point where you are experiencing one of the greatest risks of injury or death. Under-going surgery *is* inherently negative, which is why we only do it when the positive strongly outweighs it.

Comment: @Susan - Given that the first sentence of Jon's answer ends with an exclamation point, I interpreted that to indicate his opening remark was intended to be a tongue-in-cheek. I agree that the results of a successful surgery can bring both joy and relief, but I've never celebrated on the way in.

Comment: @Jon Hanna - Please do not misrepresent me. I see no cause for celebration in the death of a patient, and I am truly sorry for your loss. Organ transplant recipients do pray for the chance to undergo surgery. And, if I may be frank, my own mother died from a surgical complication. It's always a tragedy, esp. when it's totally preventable. Nonetheless, I do not see surgery as intrinsically negative.

Comment: @Susan - I don't think any of us view surgery as intrinsically negative, but most of us see at least some inherently negative aspects to it. :^) Getting back to the O.P.'s question, though, I think that these disquieting aspects of surgery are sometimes part of the motivation for using a slang term such as _under the knife_ in some contexts. The informal expression removes some of the gravity of the situation, which can be therapeutic, in a way.

Comment: @J.R. - You're right. Intrinsic is certainly an overstatement on my part. Inherent is appropriate. Perhaps it's my familiarity with medicine that makes me more optimistic towards it than most.

Comment: @Susan I don't think I'm misrepresenting you; you refer to things that are indeed worthy of celebration, I don't dispute that. I did though add that they *also* always have a risk, and most often also come with pain and discomfort. I don't think this is a matter of familiarity with medicine, since I've more than once heard medical professionals point out the risks of surgery—indeed being often more cautious than patients. The fact is, even the most trivial surgery contains a negative, and that's what "under the knife" addresses.

Comment: I think the key words in this answer are *this sort of bluntness would require a degree of familiarity to be appropriate*. As the comment thread here shows, even perfectly articulate native speakers with personal experience of the context can find it difficult to reach common ground. A friend of mine recently had (very minor) surgery under general anaesthetic for the first time in his life at age 67. Until he explicitly pointed it out, I had no idea that my flippant references to the fact that he would be "put under" were actually ***unnerving*** to him, not ***mood-lightening***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers are you shortening there for "put under the knife", or do you mean the expression "put under" for "put under general anaesthetic"? The latter I would say is a more neutral phrase, but certainly individual reaction to it would vary widely.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I totally agree. I'm glad I asked the question, and, more importantly, I'm glad I gave my student a sensible answer. I like all your answers and comments. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One of the reasons people get anxious about surgery nowadays is because surgeons go to such lengths to cover themselves against litigation by pointing out the pitfalls. The other day we accompanied our grandson's class on a school outing to an historic house, involving a bus journey of 6 miles. Before we set out the driver was obliged to point out to 22 children, all the emergency exits, how to use the seat belts etc. It was like a flight safety briefing. Because it was a different bus which collected us, we had to endure the whole thing again. Health and safety is a scaring business!

Comment: And as encouragement to any about to 'go under the knife', most routine surgery is as safe as houses. Four years ago I had a hernia op with a local anaesthetic. There was an anaesthetist on hand, but in my case he and I chatted about my history research during the 35 mins it took the surgeon to do his business. At the end I walked, with assistance, out of the theatre to a waiting room, where I was given coffee and sandwiches. After that my wife drove us home. The following day, at the surgeon's suggestion, I walked a mile, and the day after 3 miles. In ten days I was back to normal.

Comment: @Jon Hanna: I'd used *put under* as short for *put under general anaesthetic*. Which is extremely unpleasant for me, because despite advances in the technology over decades (which they *always* reassure me about, and about which they are *always* wrong/overoptimistic), I always have a bad reaction and spend far longer than most people in the post-op "recovery room". I've been through it so often that although I intensly dislike it, I don't seriously expect not to wake up afterwards. But as you say, people are right to be leery; anaesthesia is *never* 100% safe, even today.

Comment: @FumbleFingers indeed, it's the anaesthesia that I've lost people to, though I sometimes found the experience oddly pleasant, when I was put under a few times as a child.

Answer (score 1):

'Under the knife' is very casual. You would not want to say it to a student or a friend preparing for surgery as it sounds harsh, even scary. 'Preparing for surgery' or 'preparing for an operation' is the polite and tactful (that is to say, more comfortable, less alarming) way of saying it.